# creating complex nested forms with cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I've created a complex nested form, but I'm having trouble with the part where my app creates/edits records based on the input from that form correctly.

To-Do scenario: I need to enter Tasks one-by-one into my form (one task per "submit" press), from a pile of little pieces of papers with tasks written on them. Each Task has a :project_number, a :project_number_type, and an :owner written on it. In my app, these attributes are in the models ProjectNumber (for the first two) and Owner, for the last one. (I had to make a separate ProjectNumber model because my Projects can at times have multiple :project_numbers of different project_number_types.)

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :tasks, :through => :projects
end   

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :project_numbers
end

class ProjectNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  delegate :owner, :to => :project, :allow_nil => true
end
```

My form shows the correct nested `fields_for` fields for each of the attributes mentioned above. (I omitted things like my accepts_nested_attributes_for).

2 related (I think) issues:

1. My form never creates any new projects! The Cocoon gem I'm using to create nested forms has me creating form partials for each nested model. In the Project partial, since my Project model doesn't have a :number attribute itself, but instead has an association to the ProjectNumbers model which does, I just have a reference to the ProjectNumbers partial and its attributes.
2. I need my app to `edit` an existing Project with the new Task if the Task's :project_number, :project_number_type, and :owner all match those associated with an existing Project. Otherwise, it should `create` a new Project for that Task to belong to.

I read lots of little bits of code here and elsewhere, but I need something just a little more, maybe that includes the "what" as in `.first_or_initialize` and also the "where", like as in `/models/task.rb`, or `tasks_controller.rb`? Maybe I need to create something custom? Thanks so much!

**Edit: Here are the form partials**

==== `/views/tasks/_form.html.slim`

```
= simple_form_for @task do |f|
  #project
    = f.simple_fields_for :project do |project|
      = render 'project_fields', :f => project
```

==== `/views/tasks/_project_fields.html.slim`

```
.nested-fields
  .project_numbers
    = f.simple_fields_for :project_numbers do |project_number|
      = render 'project_number_fields', :f => project_number
```